# Hybris : Cannot find button for Pick Up In Store

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have configured apparel store from scratch,
but not able to find or not able to display store locator in product pages,
I have configured all actions associated with 'add to cart'.
Base store is configured with well pos, warehouses and delivery methods for pickup in store.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G21ru.png)

Please suggest

Comment: did you check point of services impex, could you please run manually from hac then see is there any error?

Comment: thanks to you, i solved it with help of next answer.... it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must check for all your configured warehouses delivery methods, it should have pickup delivery method in it and all others as required.
2. You must map all your warehouses with your POS in **INSERT_UPDATE PoS2WarehouseRel** query in pos impexes.

That's it. If this one is perfect no need to wonder anywhere.

Comment: awesome, you same my time, exactly i follow your steps ,and in few second it was working [requires to sync content catalog and product solr indexing], Thank you.